# Not able to start Sqoop Server

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

A newbie to sqoop. Forgive me if the solution is too obvious.

I installed sqoop on a Linux machine using yum repo and the installation path is /usr/lib/sqoop.

**Sqoop version:** Sqoop 1.4.5-cdh5.2.0

However I am unable to find the sqoop.sh file to start the server.
It is not available under /bin.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqoop.sh file should be in /usr/lib/sqoop/bin path. If you can't find it or the script file is not available in that location. Just Download another sqoop package and install. Sqoop package may not extract properly it seems.

Comment: NOTE: Be careful not to confuse Sqoop1 and Sqoop2. Sqoop1 has a metastore, which can be shared across all clients, but it doesn't have a traditional server. Checkout http://ingest.tips/2014/10/21/sqoop-1-or-sqoop-2/ for a quick diff of the two.

Comment: Thank you :) I have been using sqoop 1 and was confused with sqoop2 and was looking for a statup file to start the server.